# How to style the day/month/year selectors of a RadDataForm Datepicker

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm having a RadDataForm in a Nativescript-Angular App.

This RadDataForm shows a Datepicker for one of my properties.

I have read about [styling the components of a RadDataForm](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-DataForm/dataform-styling#raddataform-styling) but it's missing the part about how to style the "wheel texts" that are shown when I change the date. (Or am I missing something?)

They stay black but I need them in another color (i.e. white)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker says The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.

Comment: well that seems kinda wrong, cause there must be a way to implement a dark theme with white font (even for date picker)

Comment: Apple just announced dark theme today only,:)

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Nj15Dj&v=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker),

> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.
>
> You should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout.
>   Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their
>   intrinsic content size.

However, there are few thing that you can set. I have created a playground for [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Nj15Dj&v=3).

in your html

```
<RadDataForm [source]="album" (editorUpdate)="dfEditorUpdate($event)">
            <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="albumName" displayName="Name of Album"
                index="0"></TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="bandName" displayName="Name of Band"
                index="1"></TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="year" displayName="Release Year"
                index="2"></TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="myRating" displayName="My Rating"
                index="3"></TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="owned" displayName="Do I Own This?"
                index="4"></TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="birthDate" index="5">
                <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="DatePicker">
                    <TKPropertyEditorStyle tkPropertyEditorStyle strokeColor="#00695c"
                        strokeWidth="2" fillColor="#4db6ac" labelHidden="false"
                        labelTextSize="18" ios:labelFontName="Times New Roman"
                        android:labelFontName="sans-serif-light"
                        labelFontStyle="Italic" labelPosition="Left"
                        labelWidth="60" labelTextColor="#ffffff"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
                </TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
        </RadDataForm>
```

and in your .ts file

```
import { Color } from "tns-core-modules/color";
import { EntityProperty, DataFormEventData, RadDataForm } from "nativescript-ui-dataform";

let colorLight = new Color("#ff0000");
let colorWhite = new Color("#ffffff");
let colorDark = new Color("#4CAF50");
let colorGray = new Color("#F9F9F9");
```

and

```
public dfEditorUpdate(args: DataFormEventData) {
        if (androidApplication) {
            switch (args.propertyName) {
                case "appVolume":
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            const entityProperty: EntityProperty =
                (<RadDataForm>args.object).getPropertyByName(args.propertyName);

            switch (entityProperty.editor.type) {
                case "DatePicker":

                    const coreEditor = args.editor.editor;
                    coreEditor.subviews[0].backgroundColor = colorLight.ios;
                    coreEditor.subviews[0].setValueForKeyPath(colorWhite.ios, 'textColor');


                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For ios, you can refer to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33789261/3840213

Comment: Apparently this only makes the background of date picker in red.

Comment: Found a solution for DatePicker.....
But I'm struggling with UIPickerView.
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Nj15Dj&v=2

Comment: yeah, I tried couple of other options as well e.g. `entityProperty.editor.propertyEditorStyle.strokeColor = new Color("orange");` That changes the stroke color in form only

Comment: I think when user clicks on DatePicker, it opens Spinner and we need to find a way to change textColor there

Comment: `coreEditor.subviews[0].subviews` returns 3 subview and if we are able to track which one is UILabel then we can try to change the textColor

Comment: Done, we need to set setValueforKey, I have updated my answer, Cheers!! Happy Coding

Comment: Works great for DatePicker. But still struggling with UIPickerView.... Maybe this is topic of another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194472/discussion-between-narendra-and-naxos84).